# Pyspark Convert String to Date timestamp Column consisting two different formats

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on Chicago dataset and the Date column is in the string format and consists of dates but with two different formats:

```
Row(Date='01/10/2008 12:00'),
Row(Date='02/25/2008 08:20:53 PM')
```

I found below codes and tried both(Which I am not sure is correct) but As it consists two formats, both below codes receives error that the format is not found.

```
data_clean = data_clean.withColumn("Date_dt", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("Date",'MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss aa'),'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
data_clean.withColumn("Date_dt", to_timestamp("Date", "MM/dd/yy HH:mm")).show(1, False)
```

I have also found below solution but I need to have a datetime format including hour and minute as output:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce, to_date
def to_date_(col, formats=("MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd")):
    return coalesce(*[to_date(col, f) for f in formats])
```

What would be your suggestion to check for the format and based on it, convert it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `date_format` to convert the parsed dates to the format that you desire:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.show(truncate=0)
+----------------------+
|date                  |
+----------------------+
|01/10/2008 12:00      |
|02/25/2008 08:20:53 PM|
+----------------------+

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'date2', 
    F.date_format(
        F.coalesce(
            F.to_timestamp('date', 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a'), 
            F.to_timestamp('date', 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
        ), 
        'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm'
    )
)

df2.show(truncate=0)
+----------------------+----------------+
|date                  |date2           |
+----------------------+----------------+
|01/10/2008 12:00      |01/10/2008 12:00|
|02/25/2008 08:20:53 PM|02/25/2008 20:20|
+----------------------+----------------+
```