# Spark - Convert timestamp format of a column to another format

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am having a timestamp column which could be of any format like "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS" or "yyyy/MM/DD hh:mm:ss.SSS". I need to convert this to timestamp to a format like "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS" so that I can compare that  timestamp whether it is in Between two other timestamps

Comment: It's impossible to parse a date reliably if you don't know the format.

Comment: The format is "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS"

Comment: Your question says that's the target format.

Comment: Is the input column containing the timestamp of type string ? You can answer that by using `.printSchema()` method on your dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark Convert String to Date timestamp Column consisting two different formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67149306/pyspark-convert-string-to-date-timestamp-column-consisting-two-different-formats)

Comment: Yes @VincentDoba but the data will be stored as string , but I have to again compare the string with other two timestamps, does spark supports that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_timestamp(datetime,  "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS") from
(
    select nvl(to_timestamp(datetime, "yyyy/MM/dd' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS"),to_timestamp(datetime, "dd-MM-yyyy' 'HH:mm:ss.SSS")) as datetime
    from
    (
     select "2017/08/01 02:25:59.000" as datetime
     union all
     select "01-08-2017 02:30:59.000" as datetime 
    ) a
) b;
```